# jQuery last-child and insetBefore does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code:

```
$('#discussion li:last-child').insertBefore('<li class="other">ciao</li>');
```

The above does not work. This erases the last `<li>` element.

I wish it add another `<li>` after the last `<li>`

Here's a complete example
   https://jsfiddle.net/4q0eLkd1/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this

```js
$(document).on("click","#bott",function(){
    $('<li class="other">ciao</li>').insertAfter("#discussion li:last-child");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="discussion">
    <li class="self">ciao</li>
</ol>
<button id="bott">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add new item after the last one last you should use [$.fn.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('#discussion').append('<li class="other">ciao</li>');
```

This is the simplest and fastest solution. Behind the scene it will use native [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method.

Here is a simple demonstration.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#bott', function() {
  $('#discussion').append('<li class="other">New last item</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="discussion">
  <li>Item one</li>
</ol>
<button id="bott">click</button>
```

Comment: I bet you meant `$('#discussion').append('...');` ?